# Adding Numbers in a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am relatively new to python and have been asked to write a code where I enter a specific sequence of DNA and get various values for that sequence in return. I made a dictionary and am having trouble making the code recall the dictionary for values. The code is as follows:

```
import math

def dnaTM(seqobj):
    if isinstance(seqobj,SeqRecord):
        seq = seqobj.seq.tostring().upper()
    elif isinstance(seqobj,Seq):
        seq = seqobj.tostring().upper()
    elif isinstance(seqobj,str):
        seq = seqobj.upper()

C_primer = .000001
C_Monovalent = 1
percentage_annealed = 50
percentage_annealed = percentage_annealed/100.0

R = 1.987
deltaH = dict()
deltaS = dict()
deltaH = { 'AA/TT': -7.9, 'AT/TA': -7.2, 'TA/AT': -7.2, 'CA/GT': -8.5,
           'GT/CA': -8.4, 'CT/GA': -7.8, 'GA/CT': -8.2, 'CG/GC': -10.6,
           'GC/CG': -9.8, 'GG/CC': -8.0, 'GC_init': 0.1, 'AT_init': 2.3}
deltaS = { 'AA/TT': -22.2, 'AT/TA': -20.4, 'TA/AT': -21.3, 'CA/GT': -22.7,
           'GT/CA': -22.4, 'CT/GA': -21.0, 'GA/CT': -22.2, 'CG/GC': -27.2,
           'GC/CG': -24.4, 'GG/CC': -19.9, 'GC_init': -2.8, 'AT_init': 4.1,
           'sym': -1.4}
seqLength = len(seq)
dH = 0.2 + deltaH[str(seq[0])] + deltaH[str(seq[len(seq)-1])]
dS = -5.7 + deltaS[seq[0]] + deltaS[seq[len(seq)-1]]
for i in range(0, seqLength - 1):
    dH += deltaH[str(seq[i:i+2])]
    dS += deltaS[seq[i:i+2]]
dS = dS + 0.368 * seqLength * math.log(1)
Tm =(dH * 1000) / (dS + R * (math.log(C_primer*(1-  percentage_annealed)/percenta\
ge_annealed)-21.4164))
return Tm
```

Comment: This is Python, yes?

Comment: Please post the "trouble" you're having (error messages, actual behavior, etc)

Comment: The first issue I see is `seq` being assigned a value inside `dnaTM` but not being returned, effectively losing that value. If seq is a global, remind that unless you **explictly declare** it as a global at the start of `dnaTM`, it'll be treated as a local variable.